# Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have written code for multi window form but there is an error shown in image
[image]

i am new to JavaScript can you please help me, ask me anything you need besides from this

```
function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
    var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
    x[n].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: this is javascript ,there is no need of jquery, let me know if you need jquery solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215258/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-classname-of-undefined

Comment: Which line is the error?

Comment: x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", ""); this one

Answer (score 2):

this how you can remove class name

```
 var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 element.classList.remove("classname");
```

for adding class do this

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("classname");
```

Ref : https://caniuse.com/#search=classList

Note : I am assuming you are getting elements by this line  `x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");`

Answer (score 1):

Longtime lurker, making my first small contribution <3

Arrived at this question by trying to find a solution for the exact same error. I reckon this comes from modifying the Multi-Step form used as example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp)

This might not be the best solution, please know that I'm only a beginner.

To everyone that's trying to modify the example and getting this same error, just make sure that if you've added extra steps to the form, you've also added them to this part of the HTML code before `</form>`:

```
<!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
  <span class="step"></span>
  <span class="step"></span>
  <span class="step"></span>
  <span class="step"></span>
  <span class="step"></span>  /*This extra step added manually fixed the error for us*/
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector()`.

The Document method **querySelector()** returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

In your case you want to add `active` class on `img` tag, so before to add `class` you need to check first is already `active` is already added or not like this

```
//This function will call on image click
function onImgClik(event) {
    var activeImg = document.querySelector('img.active');
    if (activeImg) {
        activeImg.classList.remove('active');
    }
    event.target.classList.add('active');
    document.querySelector('button').disabled = false;
}
```

```js
function onImgClik(event) {
    var activeImg = document.querySelector('img.active');
    if (activeImg) {
        activeImg.classList.remove('active');
    }
    event.target.classList.add('active');
    document.querySelector('button').disabled = false;
}
```

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
}

.imageCnt{
  display: inline-flex;
  
}
.imageCnt img{
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #316eb5;
    margin: 5px;
}

.reg{
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 138px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.active{
    border-color: orange !important;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="imageCnt">
      <img onclick="onImgClik(event)"  src="https://www.qualitylogoproducts.com/images/_icons/icon_blue_add-user.svg">
      <img onclick="onImgClik(event)" src="https://www.qualitylogoproducts.com/images/_icons/icon_blue_add-user.svg">
      <img onclick="onImgClik(event)" src="https://www.qualitylogoproducts.com/images/_icons/icon_blue_add-user.svg">
      <img onclick="onImgClik(event)" src="https://www.qualitylogoproducts.com/images/_icons/icon_blue_add-user.svg">
   </div>
   <button disabled=true class="reg">Register</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run fixStepIndicator(n) fuction loop from the value of n

Comment: Don't think this is the answer OP is looking for.
In the console you can see the error "cannot read property className of undefined"

Which means that `x[i]` is undefined.

I think one of the main issues is the `var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName`.
I would suggest try to define these separately.